# Client Token generated after logging into AppRole auth backed in Harshcorp Vault doesn't allow to read secrets

Tags: hashicorp-vault

I'm integrating Harshicorp Vault into my Node JS application using [node-vault-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-vault-js) npm package. I wanted to have multiple app roles defined such as dev, stag, prod on my Vault server engine, for that purpose I have used AppRole auth backend. I have followed all the steps on [AppRole documentation](https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/auth/approle.html) and obtained the role_id and secret_id for the role to perform login as well. After that I was able to perform a login and obtained the client_token required for connecting with the Vault engine.But when using that generated client_token as vault token I get a permission denied error.

The same behavior is there even when I follow the same flow from the example in getting started to vault api [official documentation](https://www.vaultproject.io/intro/getting-started/apis.html). So its not an issue related to the node package.

Comment: Does your AppRole generated token have permission to read whatever it is you are trying to read? Did you give the app role a policy to let it do so?

Comment: I haven't gone with specific policy. Just the default one, as it was on the documentation